# grails: are plugins in a plugin, 'migrated' to the project level's plugins?

Tags: grails, plugins

We have a plugin called *Subscriber*. In its plugins is the *build-info* plugin. We can run-app and test Subscriber using run-app. We have further defined Subscriber as a plugin to our *Main* project.

To my surprise, the `build-info`, plugin appears in the list of plugins for Main. I excpected it to be 'enclosed' by Subscriber, and not immediately visible in Main. Is this apparent 'migration' of a plugin's plugin, what is supposed to happen?

I have searched the workspace for refs to *build-info* in all '*.groovy' files. It occurs in only two places (via the .link_to_grails_plugins): 1. the *build-info* plugin in Main, and 2. again, in Subscriber. So, we don't have any accidental, direct refs to *build-info* in Main.

The build-info plugin is present in the `$user_home$\.grails\projects\` in both *Subscriber\plugins* and *Main\plugins*.

Is all as it should be?

John

Answer (score 0):

If you declared the build-info as a dependency in your plugin, the default is that the build-info is **required** to Subscriber works.

You can change this behavior in the declaration of your dependency. If you don't want to export this, just set:

```
plugins {
  runtime(':theplugin:version') {
    export = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, Sergio. We do want the build-info plugin from Subscriber, to be available in the Main app. I was surprised to see it listed in the Main app's plugins. I imagined build-info would be encapsulated within Subscriber. Its presence is not a problem, if that is how Grails works. I wanted to check that what I am seeing is right, and that we don't have build-info twice, by mistake. John

Comment: Yes, what you are seeing is correct, because "main needs subscriber and subscriber needs build-info".

Comment: @JohnOrmerod the plugin dependencies work the same way standard jar file dependencies in maven, etc. would work.